# Restricting FatFractal Login Access

Tags: web-applications, custom-backend

I am using the FatFractal Javascript SDK, and I have noticed that the login() function succeeds even for usernames that have not been previously registered with my application. I would like to force users to step through a registration process before having access to my app. Is there a way to restrict login access if a username has not been previously registered on my app's backend?

Edit: Here are some simplified code snippets to help illustrate the problem...

Pertinent variables:

```
ff = new FatFractal();
var pword = $("#login-input-pw").val();
var uname = $("#login-input-email").val();
```

My login function wired to an HTML form:

```
function login(){
    ff.login(uname,pword,function(user){
        // do stuff (change page, load data, etc.)
    },function(statusCode, responseText){
        $("#loginError").html("Error: " + JSON.parse(responseText).statusMessage + ".");
        $("#login-input-pw").val('');
    });
}
```

In situations where a username is entered that has not yet been registered with my app, I would expect the ff.login() failure callback function to execute. However, for all new login attempts (obviously, an existing username + incorrect password combo do not work), the success callback function executes, and the user is granted access to the app.

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of what you've tried, or breakdown about how you're implementing this? It will help us zero in on where your problem is.

Comment: Added some sample code...thanks for the input! New to SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, FatFractal applications allow "auto registration", which is what you're seeing here. That allows a simplified flow on your clients, but isn't always what you want.

To change the behavior, open your `ff-config/application.ffdl` file. You should see a line like this, near the top:

```
SET ActivateUsersOnReg          true
```

Change that to `false`, then redeploy your app, either locally via `ffef deploylocal`, or to the cloud via `ffef deployFFFabric`, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you! Such an easy solution! :)